# Wrong sonar-scanner analysis results with nested git repositories

Tags: c, git, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

> SonarQube server 7.9.1
> SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
> Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
> Linux 4.15.0-112-generic amd64

I'm using the sonar scanner to analyse my source code. I realised that for 2 working copies I get different results on the server and was wondering why. I compared the scanner logs for both runs and detected this info in the 2nd working copy:

```
INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
```

The following directory structure should explain the differences between working copies, whereas the 2nd is a fork of the base repository:

```
└── Work1
    ├── .git
    ├── build
    |   └── config1
    ├── sonar-project.properties
    └── src

└── Work2
    ├── .git
    ├── build
    |   └── config2
    |       └── .git
    ├── sonar-project.properties
    └── src
```

I start the analysis of my 1st working copy from within the build folder (`Work1/build/config1 $> make sonar -> cd Work1; sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/bin/sonar-scanner...`) where the scanner finds the `sonar-project.properties`. The analysis is executed without any issues and the report shows perfect results.

Starting the analysis from the fork - also from within its build folder -  (`Work2/build/config2 $> make sonar -> cd Work2; sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/bin/sonar-scanner...`) the analysis does not give any impression, that something goes wrong. The results are stored on the server, but the report contains suspicious results.

As an example the following image shows the differences in case of one source file:
Left side with a file from the base repository (`Work1/src/...`), right side same file but from the fork (`Work2/src/...`)

---

[image: File comparison]

---

My impressions is, that since the 2nd analysis run log is lacking the `INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git` it cannot assign / associate the `Work2/build/config2/.git` to the sources taken from `Work2/src`.

Is my assumption correct ?

I was trying to set the options [-Dsonar.scm.provider=git](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scm-integration/) `-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=Work2/` explicitely acc. the [online documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/) and [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) but with no luck.
How can change the base folder for the SCM Provider ?

Answer (score 0):

in sonar-project.properties file add:
sonar.scm.disabled=true
or use
-Dsonar.scm.disabled=true
from cli